# EON chart formating issues via PubNub

Tags: processing, real-time, dashboard, pubnub

I am using Java (via Processing) to run Pubnub and trying to integrate that with a embedded javascript EON graph. While I am getting published values to the console (which I check with a separate subscribe only script), I don't get any EON data. I am nearly sure this has to do with the formating, but am at a total loss.

Here is what I have tried:

I have tried using the `transform` command in my embedded javascript to try to get it into the correct format. I don't fully understand what format `transform` wants to see, but I have tried strings of the values, the values as ints, and my own formatted string of the JSON format. I used the public streams [here](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/realtime-data-streams/sensor-network/) to test that my embedded code is working. And it is!!! Now I am just trying to get a processing script that duplicates the input to that code. My current attempt is below and as you can see i have tried to copy the messages being published exactly. Right now the embedded code gets the timestamp only. IE, it populates the x axis and updates as it gets new publishes, but no data is plotted. I am sure this is a formatting issue, I just have no idea what else to try.

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;
import java.util.*; 
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-ca3babb0-c900-4a8e-9524-fc2ae26847da", "sub-c-d0682e0e-04e9-11e6-a8fd-02ee2ddab7fe");

void setup()
{

  try {
    pubnub.subscribe("NSFPhaseII", new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
         pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK", new Callback() {});
      }

      @Override
        public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
          + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
          + message.toString());
      }

      public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
          + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
          + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
          + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
        public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
          + " : " + error.toString());
      }
    }
    );
  } 
  catch (PubnubException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
}

void draw() {

  Date TimeStamp = new Date();
  long current = TimeStamp.getTime()/1000; //

  //String m = "{\"ambient_temperature\":\"10\",\"radiation_level\":\"15\",\"humidity\":\"30\",\"sensor_uuid\":\"probe-dff03902\",\"photosensor\":\"39\",\"timestamp\":"+str(current)+"}";
  String m = "{ambient_temperature:'10',radiation_level:'15',humidity:'30',sensor_uuid:'probe-dff03902',photosensor:'39',timestamp:"+str(current)+"}";
  println(m);

  Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
      System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
      System.out.println(error.toString());
    }
  };
  pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", m, callback);
  delay(5000);
}
```

I have also tried to use JSON objects in java, but I get really weird errors with `publish`. Before runtime `publish` is highlighted with the following error: "The function "Publish()" expectes parameters like: "publish(String, JSONObject,Callback)". Which is odd because I am giving it all those things. Then at runtime I get: "The method publish(String,JSONObject,Callback) in the type PubnubCoreAsync is not applicable for the arguments(String,JSONObject,net Callback(){}). Which is even more odd as the error pre-runtime was that I needed to supply all those exact things. I beleive the issue is that the libraries required for pubnub have a JSONObject type and so does processing and the two types do not work well.

Anyway, here is my embedded javascript which is a direct copy from [here](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/blob/master/examples/transform.html):

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.10/eon.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.10/eon.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
    // using the example stream from 
    // http://www.pubnub.com/developers/data-streams/sensor-network
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key: 'sub-c-d0682e0e-04e9-11e6-a8fd-02ee2ddab7fe', //rebound
      //subscribe_key: 'sub-c-5f1b7c8e-fbee-11e3-aa40-02ee2ddab7fe',
        ssl: true
    });
    eon.chart({
        pubnub: pubnub,
        history: false,
        channel: 'NSFPhaseII',
        //channel: 'pubnub-sensor-network',
        limit: 100,
        rate: 10,
        ssl: true,
        debug: true,
        generate: {
            transition: {
                duration: 3
            },
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                x: 'x'
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%H:%m:%S'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        transform: function(m) {
            return {
                eon: {
                    'Humidy': m.humidity,
                    'Temperature': m.ambient_temperature,
                    'Light': m.photosensor
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my processing .pde. In this version I have it setup to publish the JSON.

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;
processing.data.JSONObject write;
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-ca3babb0-c900-4a8e-9524-fc2ae26847da", "sub-c-d0682e0e-04e9-11e6-a8fd-02ee2ddab7fe");



void setup()
{
  write = new processing.data.JSONObject();

try {
  pubnub.subscribe("NSFPhaseII", new Callback() {
      //@Override
      //public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
      //    pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK", new Callback() {});
      //}

      @Override
      public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                     + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                     + message.toString());
      }

      public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                     + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                     + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                     + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                     + " : " + error.toString());
      }
    }
  );
} catch (PubnubException e) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
}
}

void draw(){


  write.setFloat("var1", random(10));
  write.setFloat("var2", random(10));
  write.setFloat("var3", random(10));

  //saveJSONObject(write, "data/new.json");


  pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", write,new Callback() {});
  delay(15000);
}
```

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Now I will try to explain how I solved this. The solution spans both formatting issues with EON and JSON object issues with processing. I will try to hit both. To get it to work, I used the public pubnub sensor channel as a good resource: https://www.pubnub.com/developers/realtime-data-streams/sensor-network/ My basic approach was to parrot this channel on my own channel and then convert it over to what I actually wanted ot be sending.

JSON formatting: 
The long of the short of it is, if you want EON graphs to transform your published values correctly, the must be sent as a org.json.JSONObject in your publish command. I was never able to use a publish command that took a string and did the JSONing on its own. Even when I produced the exact same format as the input to publish that should have been converted to a JSON EON rejected it.

So, first point, use a org.json.JSONObject as the input to Publish.

That brings us to how to create such an object in Processing which is not easy.

org.json.JSONObject Processing:
Because Processing has its own JSONObject type, the org.json.JSONObject must be used explicitly. From there, you need to use the syntax described [here](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/) to format the JSON object correctly. There is a twist, the new JSON object creation must be put in a try statement or else Processing will complain that there is an checked unhandled exception. This is covered in more detail [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/67382#Comment_67382) by people smarter than me! Here is some example code on using the library org.json.JSONObject library:

```
import org.json.*;  

void setup() {
   String str = "{ \"name\": \"Alice\", \"age\": 20 }";
   org.json.JSONObject json;
   try {
     json = new org.json.JSONObject(str);
     String n = json.getString("name");
     int a = json.getInt("age");
     println(n + " " + a);
  }
  catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
     System.err.println(e);
     exit();
  }

}

void draw() {
}
```

Once you have this object, you can use the publish command as advertized to publish things to an EON chart!

Here is the updated code from above that now creates a live EON chart. This code sends 6 values every 5s to the chart:

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;
import java.util.*; 
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-ca3babb0-c900-4a8e-9524-fc2ae26847da", "sub-c-d0682e0e-04e9-11e6-a8fd-02ee2ddab7fe");

org.json.JSONObject m;
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
      System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
      System.out.println(error.toString());
    }
  };

void setup()
{
  try {
    pubnub.subscribe("NSFPhaseII",callback);
  } 
  catch (PubnubException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
}

void draw() {

  Date TimeStamp = new Date();
  long current = TimeStamp.getTime()/1000; //
  String m1 = "\"T0\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m2 = "\"T5\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m3 = "\"T6\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m4 = "\"T8\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m5 = "\"T9\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m6 = "\"T13\":\""+str(random(10))+"\",";
  String m7 = "\"timestamp\":\""+current+"\",";

  try {
    m = new org.json.JSONObject("{"+m1+m2+m3+m4+m5+m6+m7+"}");
  }
  catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    exit();
  }
  pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", m, callback);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Hope this helps the 3 people using processing to do something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Where is your implementation of `Callback()` for this `publish` in this code:

`pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", write,new Callback() {});`

`new Callback() {}` is an empty implementation of Callback

You need to pass an instance of the Callback class that has a full implementation like this:

```
Callback callback = new Callback() {
  public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
  public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
    System.out.println(error.toString());
  }
};
    Callback callback = new Callback() {
  public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
  public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
    System.out.println(error.toString());
  }
};
pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", write, callback);
```

This:

```
pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", write, callback);
```

as opposed to:

```
pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", write,new Callback() {});
```

Comment: Is that required for EON charts? This does not remedy the formatting errors.  I now get the error:

Comment: I'm just addressing your Java code. That publish shouldn't work due to the fact that it doesn't have an implementation for the Callback class parameter.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think this is the core issue. I think what might be happening is that both processing and the pubnub library have type `JSONObject`. Above you will see I have  `processing.data.JSONObject write;` instead of the normal `JSONObject write`. When I have a full callback it says it is looking for a `org.json.JSONObject` not a `processing.data.JSONObject`. The issue is that I have no idea how to produce a org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: The publish does work as I can subscribe and see the values that are being published.

Comment: But I do appreciate the feedback, the error changes slightly which is perhaps going to be helpful.